# pushing new elements in angular object

Tags: angularjs, arrays

Hy, so I have this code :

```
  angular.forEach(parentsId, function(parentId, key) {
    $scope.getContentByParent("Courses",parentId,function(data){

      $scope.Courses.push(data);

    });
  });

  $scope.getContentByParent = function(table,parentId,callback) {

  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('table', table);
  data.append('parentId', parentId);

  $http.post('../server/Model/content/get_content_by_parent.php', data, {
    transformRequest: angular.identity,
    headers: {'Content-Type': undefined}
  })
   .then(function (data) {
     data = data.data;
     callback(data);
    });
   };
```

and in html

```
 <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12" ng-repeat="Course in Courses">
      <div class="ribbon ribbon_primary">
        <div class="ribbon__title">
          {{Course.Name}}
        </div>
        <div class="ribbon__content" ng-bind-html="Course.Description">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

So the problem is that when I push a new element in my object, it pushes it as an array, like this :

```
 [Log] Array (2) (home-controller.js, line 23)
    0 [Object] (1)
    1 [Object] (1)

  Array Prototype
```

How can I push it as a new object element?

Comment: Can you please add `getContentByParent` method?

Comment: Just edited it.

Comment: what would be your expected output ?

Comment: [Object] (2)  Object Prototype

Comment: I need an object with 2 elements instead of an array with 2 objects

Comment: shows the console log of data before it pass to callback function. data = data.data; console.log('data: ' data);
     callback(data);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I got it :

```
 $scope.getCoursesContent = function(parentsId){

  angular.forEach(parentsId, function(parentId, key) {
    $scope.getContentByParent("Courses",parentId,function(data){

      angular.forEach(data,function(Course, key){
        $scope.Courses.push(Course);
      });

    });
  });
};
```